# CakePHPのアソシエーションが上手くいきません

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPのアソシエーションモデルが上手くいきません

画像のようなDBを設計したのですが、以下のようにModelのアソシエーションのコードを書いたのですが、Studentモデルからstoc_wishとctos_wishのモデルにアクセスできません。

解決方法を教えてください

```
// student.php
class Student extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Team');
    public $hasMany = array('Stoc_wish', 'Ctos_wish');

}

// stoc_wish.php
class Stoc_wish extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Student', 'Cuser');
}

// ctos_wish.php
class Ctos_wish extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Student', 'Cuser');
}
```

ちなみに、CakePHP2.6を使ってます[image]

Answer (score 1):

解決しました

命名規則が間違っていました

正しくは、StocWish,CtosWishでした